# Copy all registry entries from one location to the other in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I am using Inno Setup to copy all entries in the registry from one location to another. Can you please advise on how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to copy registry tree elsewhere.

- You can use [WinAPI `RegCopyTree`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regcopytreew) (but you will also need to import and use `RegOpenKey`, `RegCreateKey` and `RegCloseKey`).
- If you want to stick with plain Pascal Script, you would have to use [`RegGetSubkeyNames`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_reggetsubkeynames) and [`RegGetValueNames`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_reggetvaluenames) to collect all subkeys and values and copy/write them one-by-one.

  For some example, see `Copy32BitUninstallKeyTo64bit` in [Inno Setup: Keep existing 32-bit installation path for upgrades, use 64-bit path for new installations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43142563/850848#43142861) – though it does copy only all values (and of specific types only), not subkeys